# Случайный спавн обьектов

Tags: unity3d

Как сделать так, чтобы точка спавна объекта случайно выбиралась из 5 заданных точек?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаешь объект спавна и в него расчитываешь случайный спавн, а дальше пользуешься уже им:

```
var spawn = spawnsArray[Random.Range(0, spawnsArray.Lenght)];
//spawn.SpawnEnemy();
```